# Update the data instead of adding it to my table in javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, pusher

I'm working with the pusher api and I need to update the data instead of adding it to my table. The data is displayed in an html table I have in my index, The data is coming in but its making a new row every time a new state is called, I want to just update the data instead of adding a new row, only add a new row if the state has not been called.

How do update instead of add each state's data?

index.html

```
<div class='test'>  
</div>

<table class="table tg">
<tr>
<th class="tg-ufsm">Location</th>
<th class="On the line tg-ufsm">Calls on the Line</th>
<th class="tg-ufsm">Total Calls</th>
<th class="tg-ufsm">Average Duration</th>
<th class="tg-ufsm">% Of All Calls Across All States</th>
</tr>

</table>
```

And here is the javascript

```
 channel.bind('call', function(data) {
  var location = data.location;
  var call_id = data.call_id;
  var status = data.status;   

  if(!tableStates[location]) {
    tableStates.location = statesEmpty();
    $('.table').append('<tr><td>' + location + '<td>' + status + '</td><td class="count"> </tr>');
    $('.test').append( $('<div class="myTable ' + location + '">  <div class="count"></div> </div>') );
  }

 tableStates.location.count += 1;
 $('.table').find('.count').text(tableStates.location.count);


});
```

Comment: What is a "call to each state"?  I don't understand what you're trying to count.

Comment: The live data are calls coming in frome each states, I want to count the calls from each state if that makes sense. ex : how many calls from NY and update that data in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is a mistake. May it be that in the setence `tableStates.location = statesEmpty();` what it means is `tableStates[location] = statesEmpty();`

Related to your problem i would save the nodes that it have been previous generated so then it would be easly acces to them to modifie it. Here is a possible way to do it:

```
channel.bind('call', function(data) {
  var location = data.location;
  var call_id = data.call_id;
  var status = data.status;   

  if(!tableStates[location]) {
    tableStates[location] = statesEmpty();
    tableStates[location].nodes = {
      location: $('<td>' + location + '</td>'),
      status: $('<td>' + status + '</td>'),
      count: $('<td>0</td>')
    };

    $('.table').append(
      $('<tr></tr>')
      .append(tableStates[location].nodes.location)
      .append(tableStates[location].nodes.status)
      .append(tableStates[location].nodes.count)
    );
    $('.test').append( $('<div class="myTable ' + location + '">  <div class="count"></div> </div>') );
  }

 tableStates[location].count += 1;
 tableStates[location].nodes.count.html(
   tableStates[location].count
 );


});
```

And here is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FNCH5isV8h5ULs16PVww?p=preview

There is also other solution, which in my opinion it may be better in terms of separation of concerns. It's posible to store only the data in some object and then with this data rewrite all the entire table. Something like this:

```
var tableStates = {};
var table = document.querySelector('table.table.tg');

function tableTemplate(tableStates) {
    table.innerHTML = [
      '<tr>',
      '  <th class="tg-ufsm">Location</th>',
      '  <th class="On the line tg-ufsm">Calls on the Line</th>',
      '  <th class="tg-ufsm">Total Calls</th>',
      '  <th class="tg-ufsm">Average Duration</th>',
      '  <th class="tg-ufsm">% Of All Calls Across All States</th>',
      '</tr>',
      Object.keys(tableStates).map(function (tableState) {
        return [
          '<tr>',
          '<td>', tableState, '</td>',
          '<td>', tableStates[tableState].status, '</td>',
          '<td>', tableStates[tableState].count, '</td>',
          '</tr>'
        ].join('');
      }).join('')
    ].join('');
}

channel.bind('call', function(data) {

  if(!tableStates[data.location]) {
    tableStates[data.location] = {
      status: data.status,
      count: 0
    }
  } else {
    tableStates[data.location] = {
      status: data.status,
      count: tableStates[data.location].count + 1
    };
  }

  tableTemplate(tableStates);

});
```

you can see it here working http://plnkr.co/edit/3xLUXhth8Ka3cVBXR17j?p=preview

This solution allows you to separate the presentation to your data mode. This helps in the maintanabilty of the code.

Also if you need to cove IE < 8 (http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector) you don't need to use jQuery for css selectors. Instead of this you can use document.querySelector